# Will my open source project be illegal in certain countries if I include openssl?

Tags: encryption, reference, openssl

I have a small open source project and I am about to add some encryption to it.  I am wondering if this will restrict where developers can contribute from.  If so where are these laws so stringent?  Is there a reliable up to date standard available on the web in regards to this matter?  Should I care about recruiting programmers from all over the world?

Comment: SO is not here to answer legal questions.

Comment: I'd suggest the appropriate information will be in the OpenSSL license.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the [Crypto Law Survey](http://www.cryptolaw.org/). It looks up-to-date; whether it's reliable, you should ask your lawyer. Several countries (e.g. Israel) have laws that require a license to operate cryptographic software.

I would leave it to the contributors to make sure they comply with their local laws. If you get complaints that people would like to contribute but can't because of the local law, study the specific case, then then search for a specific solution.

Comment: Unfortunately that link has rotted